# Automatically play and restart YouTube video via <p:media>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, youtube, media

How to play a YouTube video automatically without clicking the button using `<p:media>`? And how to restart it automatically?

```
 <p:media value="#{myviewBean.youtubeURL}" 
       binding="#{myviewBean.youtubeMedia}" 
       width="420" 
       height="320" 
       player="flash"/>
```

Comment: BalusC thanks for modifications