# Using <p:media> to play YouTube automatically

Tags: jsf, primefaces, youtube, media, autoplay

This question is (similar question) related to this link below
Please see this link:

[Automatically play and restart YouTube video via <p:media>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929216/automatically-play-and-restart-youtube-video-via-pmedia)

I am still learning JSF and I did a lot of research to play youtube automatically without click on button. but I do not solve it yet.
Could you please help me .

Comment: My project is to display information and media in one screen. So I did that very well except Youtube. I mean the youtube is working by clicking on play. Therefore I want to play it automatically and restart it again without click on play. I tried to use <f:param> with it but it doesn't work.  Please see link above. regards

Comment: I also used this link to do it but it does not play automatically 
https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html

Comment: If you're not satisfied with the respons, edit and improve the existing question. Do not re-ask the same question again.

Comment: Dear  BalusC. Firstly, I do not say I am not satisfied. I just need someone help me if it is possible and I am sorry for bothering you.Secondly, I don't have any idea to improve it because it is still not work automatically.regards

Comment: BalusC you reported that my previous question was answered. Could you please tell me where is the answer.

Comment: I didn't do that. This is just a standard message.